# Bash coproc with python

Tags: bash, shell-script, coprocesses

I am playing with the `coproc` of Bash and I am failing to understand something.

I started with the following example:

## Example#1

```
$ coproc MY_BASH { bash; }
[1] 95244
$ echo 'ls -l; echo EOD' >&"${MY_BASH[1]}"
$ is_done=false; while [[ "$is_done" != "true" ]]; do
>   read var <&"${MY_BASH[0]}"
>   if [[ $var == "EOD" ]]; then
>      is_done="true"
>   else
>      echo $var
>   fi
> done
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file10.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file3.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file4.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file5.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file6.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file7.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file8.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 0 Nov 11 13:00 file9.txt
$
```

Here we can see that the current Bash shell is able to create a coprocess and interact with it.

## Example 2

In this case, I switch from a `bash` coprocess to a `python` coprocess:

```
$ coproc MY_BASH { python; }
[1] 95244
$ echo 'print("hello"); print("EOD");' >&"${MY_BASH[1]}"
$ is_done=false; while [[ "$is_done" != "true" ]]; do
>   read var <&"${MY_BASH[0]}"
>   if [[ $var == "EOD" ]]; then
>      is_done="true"
>   else
>      echo $var
>   fi
> done
```

In this scenario the program hangs and gets blocked.

I have the impression that I am forgetting to send something in the input.

Any help to better understand what is going on will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here…

First, you need to use the `-i` option of Python so that it enters interactive mode and reads commands from stdin for execution.  So:

```bash
coproc MY_BASH { python -i ; }
```

Next, Python does not delimit commands with semicolons, so you need to use newlines to separate your commands:

```bash
echo $'print("Hello, World!")\nprint("EOD")' >&"${MY_BASH[1]}"
```

Comment: Hey @GregBarret! Thanks a lot for your answer, in fact there were several problems.
The first one was that the command I tried to use, `python` didn't exist in my system (maybe because a recent update), so I needed to use one available `python3.10` in my case. 
Once I noticed it, I did the modifications you suggested (replacing the semicolons with newlines and added the `-i` flag) and it worked perfectly.
Thanks a lot Greg!